# pandas concat inner join: a join with an empty DataFrame does not yield an empty DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm concatenating two pandas `DataFrame`s column-wise (`axis=1`), with `join='inner'` like so:

```
import pandas as pd

print('pd.__version__ = ', pd.__version__)

DF_empty = pd.DataFrame()
DF_a = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2]}, index=[0, 1])
DF_b = pd.DataFrame({'b': [3]}, index=[1])

DF_empty_inner_a = pd.concat([DF_empty, DF_a], axis=1, join='inner')
DF_a_inner_b = pd.concat([DF_a, DF_b], axis=1, join='inner')

print('empty inner a:\n{}\n'.format(DF_empty_inner_a))
print('a inner b:\n{}'.format(DF_a_inner_b))
```

and I get:

```
pd.__version__ = 0.19.2

empty inner a:
   a
0  1
1  2

a inner b:
   a  b
1  2  3
```

but I was expecting that `DF_empty_inner_a` would be empty.

Is this a bug, a feature, or my misconception?

Comment: In my opinion it is bug. `merge` alternative works nice `print (pd.merge(DF_empty, DF_a, left_index=True, right_index=True))`

Comment: I report it [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15328)

Comment: I think as you have not mentioned the Index value, pandas wouldn't consider the empty dataframe. However, if you mention the index value while creating the empty dataframe, the result will produce like this: Empty DataFrame
Columns: []

Comment: @Chandan, I get `Empty DataFrame Columns: [] Index: []` either way (for `DF_empty = pd.DataFrame()`, and for `DF_empty = pd.DataFrame(index=[])`).